# Wicket: OnChange event doesnt Work anymore

Tags: java, wicket

I try to add some on change behavior to some fields, but they dont trigger.

Code:

```
    TextField test = new TextField("test", Model.of(""));
    test.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    test.add(new OnChangeAjaxBehavior() {

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
           setResponsePage(ProductPage.class);
        }
    });
    add(test)
```

Markup:

```
 <input type="text" wicket:id="test" />
```

I dont get why this doesn`t work.. I just know that this code did work some day..

----edit----

some additional info: we use wicket and java 7. We share and merge our code with svn. The, in my eyes, very strange behavior is that this code works with exactly ONE pc. With every other PC this doesn´t work.

More strange is, that NO `onchange` behavior triggers anymore. Even if I debug the code the compiler doesn´t jump into the `onUpdate` method, while there are `onchange` behavior which already did their job.

We actually got no clue why.. JavaScript is in every browser aktiviated and we tried it with IE, Chrome, Opera and Firerfox

Comment: Have you checked Wicket's Ajax debug window?

Answer (score 0):

check this:
[OnChangeAjaxBehavior](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org$maven2@org.apache.wicket$wicket-core@6.18.0@org$apache$wicket$ajax$form$OnChangeAjaxBehavior.java)

as you can see

```
if (!(component instanceof TextField || component instanceof TextArea)) {
   ...
}
```

so u might try another behavior, for example this should work fine:

```
new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange"){...}
```

Comment: if you read more this check is just to put change event if not textfield, it will not change anything if he take the parent, so nothing related to his issue....